# Rail's ActiveRecord find_each with DISTINCT select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to get a list of all unique emails I have in my database and process them in batch using `find_each`.

The code below works fine until it has more then 1000 records (batch size) to process. Then it breaks after the 1000th record with the error message `Primary key not included in the custom select clause`

```
Tourist.select('DISTINCT email').where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today-  1).find_in_batches do |group|
    something
end
```

So, how can I chain all this:

- I only need a specific field (email)
- I need them to be unique
- I need a where a clause
- I need a find_each

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it manually with a loop `limit` and `offset`

```
batch_size = 1000
offset = 0

loop do
  emails = Tourist.where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today-1).select('DISTINCT email').limit(batch_size).offset(offset)
  emails.each do |email| 
    # your stuff
  end 

  break if emails.size < batch_size
  offset += batch_size
end
```

Of course this is needed only if the request will retrieve a large number of emails. Otherwise simply use `Tourist.where(condition).pluck('DISTINCT email').each { |email| your stuff }`