# Rails & PostgreSQL: find distinct records by custom field in batch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Suppose I'd like to query a list of actors who commented on an item.

A naive Rails query would be:

```
Comment.where(commentable_id: 1).select(:commenter_id).distinct.find_each.map(&:commenter_id)
# => ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

When adding order

```
Comment.where(commentable_id: 1).select(:commenter_id).order(:commenter_id).distinct.find_each.map(&:commenter_id)
# => Scoped order is ignored, it's forced to be batch order.
# => ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

It doesn't work because [find_in_batches](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches) doesn't support order. I can do it with manual batching [as proposed in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424702/2771889), but is it possible to do via Rails or is there a nicer way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it next way

```
Comment.where(commentable_id: 1).pluck(:commenter_id).uniq
```

Or

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  # normal find_each does not use given order but uses id asc
  def self.find_each_with_order(options={})
    raise "offset is not yet supported" if options[:offset]

    page = 1
    limit = options[:limit] || 1000

    loop do
      offset = (page-1) * limit
      batch = find(:all, options.merge(:limit=>limit, :offset=>offset))
      page += 1

      batch.each{|x| yield x }

      break if batch.size < limit
    end
  end
end
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each#698-Will-discard-any-order-option

Comment: this is not **in batch**

Comment: why do you need to do it with batch?

Comment: @eugene_trebin There are many reasons, but one is it is possible to have too many records to fit into memory. Without batching, all the records must be allocated in memory at the same moment.

Comment: Thank you for 'batch' definition. But that doesn't answer my question))) However it doesn't matter already...